# SDWebImage give rise to memory to a high value

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I don't know if I write a bug or not when I use SDWebImage to load a lot of image from the server, every time I scroll my list(tableview or collectionview), the memory raise to a high value (eg. 200M).
this is my code in the cell:

```
 - (void)loadInfo(NSDictionary *)dic
    {
        self.imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dic[@"image_src"]];
    }
```

I am sure my cell reuse is ok, I want to know this is why, Thanks.

Comment: 200M is fine.  If you want to make the cache smaller you can use `SDImageCache sharedImageCache].maxMemoryCost = [size in pixel - each pixel is generally 4 bytes]`

Comment: when I add this code, when memory raise to a level, I got a crash, even I can not read the reason, because the xcode show a message "Lost connection to 'my iphone' "

Comment: Just now, I make a test, when memory is equal to 750M, I got a crash...

Comment: how large is each image?

Comment: @Jon Rose about 50k

Comment: that weird. If it is taking up 200MB that would mean that there are 4000 images being kept!  I have never experience anything like this and have used SDWebImage a lot. What do the imageURL look like? is it possible that it is confusing the method `cacheKeyForURL:` in `SDWebImageManager`?

Comment: @JonRose I just use this method: sd_setImageWithURL and maybe some images have more large size, just now I cached images in disk, then read from disk every time, and the issues is resolved, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you're scrolling, you're loading a lot of pictures asynchronously making you have many threads and asynchronous downloads, thus the memory issue. However I suggest the following for you.

1- don't download high resolution images from the web, choose a default resolution and let your server minimize the resolution before sending the image if possible (saves a lot of memory)

2- It is a good idea to cache the images so that you don't download them again when their cell appear (SDWebImage provides that cache feature).

Those 2 steps should make your app okay.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply, that's right, that is my favorite way, but my server can't change this for me, because don't think this is a issue, so cache feature may be a good way, I will make a test.

Comment: it's not a good idea to do cache test.because SDWebimage has already cached these iamges for you.

Comment: @iticle But the memory is very high. In my opinion, I cache the image on disk, next time I load Image from disk directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];`.Do not allow SDWebimage decompress images to memory.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of SDWebImage you used, I can't find ShouldDecompressImages in SDImageCache class, and I add this code:[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setShouldDecompressImages:NO]; got the same result. -_-